# Sort map by value where map is an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a map by value where the values are arrays.

For example the map below:

```
{'let1': ['art', 'can'], 'let2': ['own', 'kit', 'dig'], 'let3': ['art', 'zero']}
```

I would like to sort it as:

```
{'let1': ['art', 'can'], 'let3': ['art', 'zero'], 'let2': ['own', 'kit', 'dig']}
```

Is it possible using the JavaScript `sort()` method?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you show us a bigger picture? It might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting of an object is not advised. It should be treated as a look-up. You should convert the key-value pairs to entry tuples and sort the value at index 1 (aka the value array).

See: [*Sorting object property by values*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

```js
let obj = {
  'let1': ['art', 'can'],
  'let2': ['own', 'kit', 'dig'],
  'let3': ['art', 'zero']
};

console.log(Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) =>
  a[1].join(',').localeCompare(b[1].join(','))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Result

```
[
  [ "let1", [ "art", "can"        ] ],
  [ "let3", [ "art", "zero"       ] ],
  [ "let2", [ "own", "kit", "dig" ] ]
]
```